# is_user_logged_in() not working in homepage

Tags: php, functions, widgets, users, login

I am building a website using the Eduma theme and I am using `is_user_logged_in()` inside the logic of my login / register widgets but it does not seem to work in the homepage of my site. After logging in successfully the text of my widget remains "login" but as soon as i go to a different page like blog, it will change to "logout".

My website can be accessed here: https://elingos.com 
You can try logging in with these credentials

- id: TestUser
- pass: 1234

I am not experience at all with php, so I really have no idea where to put my hands. I've put `functions.php` and other files in a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/AlbertoMontalesi/d8f1f5f4b311285e379efd497bb6d123) if it may help.

Thank you very much for the assistance :)

Comment: Are you using any sort of caching plugin?

Comment: @JacobPeattie according to "WhatRuns" he's using W3 Total Cache 0.9.7

Comment: @JacobPeattie as Wilco said I am using W3 Total Cache 0.97

Comment: Well it sounds like the plugin is caching the logged out version of the page. Make sure it's set up to not cache for logged in users.